# Cannot resolve symbol 'RoadManager'

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies

I get an error like this. What should I do? do i have to do? do i have to add something in my dependencies?
this my code

```
//, MapboxMap.OnMapClickListener, PermissionsListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private MapView mapView;
    private Button button;
    private MapboxMap mapboxMap;
    private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
    private LocationComponent locationComponent;
    // variables for calculating and drawing a route
    private DirectionsRoute currentRoute;
    private static final String TAG = "DirectionsActivity";
    private NavigationMapRoute navigationMapRoute;
    private RoadManager roadManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

this is my dependencies

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828' //2.5.2
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'//vcoba kalo error ini diapus
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.6@aar'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.42.1'
    implementation('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.8.1') {
        exclude group: 'group_name', module: 'module_name'
    }
}
```

what should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RoadManager is part of OSMBonusPack.

First of all, you should follow [OSMBonusPack HowToInstall](https://code.google.com/archive/p/osmbonuspack/wikis/HowToInclude.wiki) guide.

And then follow [OSMBonusPack](https://code.google.com/archive/p/osmbonuspack/wikis/Tutorial_0.wiki) tutorial.